# not able to write console output in textfile

Tags: c#, .net, file

i want to write the console output in a text file. this is my code.

```
String filePath = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/New folder/";
            String fileName = "newop.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
            {
                File.Create(filePath + fileName).Dispose();

                using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(filePath + fileName, false))
                {

                    sr.WriteLine(currLink.Url);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(currLink.Url);
            ie.Element("button_next").Click();

        }
```

Comment: So, did you get the console output into a text file?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do: `File.Create(filePath + fileName).Dispose();`?

Comment: yes i want to write the console output in text file

Comment: File.Create(filePath + fileName).Dispose(); this is used to check whether the file is created or not

Comment: No, it is used to create an empty file, it is not needed, StreamWriter will create the file for you.

Comment: oh can you tell me the exact code.bcoz i am new to .net

Comment: The code you've posted should in fact work. Can you tell us whether it did?

Comment: no its creating a file.but it prints only one line.But in my console i got more than 500 lines.

Comment: That is because the code as posted overwrites the file each time. Use `, true` in the call to `new StreamWriter` to make it append instead of overwrite.

Comment: show your complete code, i.e. the loop around the snippet you posted

Comment: also, your `if` checks if the file exists or not. If it does exist **you never write to file**. If you always want to write to file, you shouldn't have an if stating that it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you want is this:

```
String filePath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder";
String fileName = "newop.txt";
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), true))
{
    sr.WriteLine(currLink.Url);
}
ie.Element("button_next").Click();
```

This will append to the file every time you call it.

If you want to reset the file at the start of the program, use this piece of code:

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), string.Empty);
```

This will create an empty file for you.

The rest of the code you had in your question does the following:

1. It only runs once, when the file does not exist, the next time, when the file *does* exist, the code to write to the file no longer runs (`if (!File.Exists...`)
2. It creates an empty file each time (`File.Create(....`)
3. It overwrites the file when opening it with StreamWriter (the `, false` in the call to the constructor)

There's no need to do any of this, simply ask StreamWriter to open the file for writing, appending if it exists (`, true`), and write to it. Remove the check if the file exists, remove the call to `File.Create`, or move it if you want to reset the file at some point.

Comment: still it printing only one line

Comment: Without seeing the code as you have it now, it is impossible to follow up that comment. I can vouch for the fact that the code I posted above will keep adding to an existing file. The question is what else you're doing as well?